# Is this a proper use of "which" as a relative pronoun?

Tags: relative-pronouns, determiners

In a [description of a programmatic operator in TCL](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm#M12), I encountered a usage of "which" that I didn't know about before:

> < > <= >= Boolean less, greater, less than or equal, and greater than or equal. Each operator produces 1 if the condition is true, 0 otherwise. These operators may be applied to strings as well as numeric operands, **in which case** string comparison is used.

I don't understand what kind of *which* this is. I don't think it is a pronoun as I used to know e.g. in *This is the book which you loved to have*.

Comment: The linked question seems to be the same as mine but the answer given is confusing to me. In short, I infer that this usage is correct and is called "relative determinant". Right?

Comment: Close -- it's a *determin**er***. Many determiners besides *which* can stand by themselves and act as nominals (think of *such*, *many*, *most*, *all*, for instance), and some of these are relatives: *which*, *whichever*, *whatever*.

Answer (score 0):

This is the book which you loved.

The word which is a relative pronoun used in the defining relative clause "which you loved". In informal English, you can replace it with  "that" if you want to.

In the other sentence, "which" is a relative determiner, as commented by StoneyB. Please see his answer on "which as a relative determiner".

Comment: In the question OP asks about, with *in which case*, *which* is not a pronoun but a determiner.

Comment: StoneyB, Thanks for enlightening me. I have edited my answer accordingly.